# VBA Listbox becomes unresponsive after first use

Tags: vba, listbox

I have a VBA (Excel 2010) system which involves selecting an item from a listbox and then displaying it in another form. Here is a very simplified version of what happens.

```
' Part of frmForm1 code module
sub lstListbox_Click

dim MyEvent as string
dim i as integer

i=me.lstListbox.listindex
MyEvent=me.lstlistbox.list(i)

'  Now show the item in the second form

Load frmForm2
me.hide
ThisWorkbook.LoadDataIntoForm2 (frmForm2, MyEvent)
frmForm2.show

unload frmForm2
me.show

end sub
```

The listbox accepts the click, and first the event (the event handler is giver above). Key parts of the event handler are:

- Load the second form (to display the detail data)
- Pass the second form as a UserForm parameter to a procedure (LoadDataIntoForm2)
- Hide the host form (frmForm1) and show the second form (frmForm2)
- When the second form processes an Exit click, the code looks like this:

' Part of frmForm2 code module

```
sub cmdExit_Click

me.hide

end sub
```

The first time round it works fine - but when I return to frmForm1 (in the tail end of the lstListBox_Click procedure), even though the rest of the form is operative, the listbox remains stubbornly unresponsive.

I've managed to abstract this down to a little demo system if that would help - the same behavior is seen there. (It's regular .xls file, but that seems not to be easily acceptable as an upload)

Has anyone seen this before? And does anyone have any ideas how I might get this to work the way I want it to?

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: I've not seen it before, but does it do the same thing if you hook into the `_Change` event?

Answer (score 1):

The default for the `.Show` method is to make the form [modal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window). Explicitly set it to modeless:

```
Sub lstListbox_Click
...
Me.Show vbModeless

End Sub
```